# Can requests made from workers be proxied through a service worker?

Tags: web-worker, service-worker

I've registered a service worker with the root (`./`) scope and it's successfully caching and serving assets that my main page requests -- yay! However, my page also spawns a web worker which makes network requests of its own and those do not seem to be hitting my service worker. Do I need to register the service worker in the web worker as well or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This is actually working in Chrome so Firefox-only issue at the moment. Mozilla's Ben Kelly pointed me to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1206947 so check there for status.